# Can I store a password safely in a BlazeMeter test plan?

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I want to make a request at the beginning of my test plan to get an auth token which will be sent with all the requests in my test plan. Is there a way to store the password required to get that auth token without other users being able to access it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing as "BlazeMeter test plan", there is [JMeter Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) which is basically [XML file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) hence it is not possible to "securely" store passwords there because it will be saved as the plain text and everyone will be able to download it and see the password.

You can use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in the test plan to read the password from a JMeter Property.

[image]

Once done for local executions you will be able to set the password via [-J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -Jpassword=secret -t test.jmx ...
```

In BlazeMeter test execution you can use [JMeter Properties](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005918945-JMeter-Properties) section to define the desired value of the `password` property

[image]